# "'type' object is not subscriptable" working with dataclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-dataclasses

Trying to work with entering data from a csv document into a dataclass.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass

class deck:
    name:str = ''
    length:float = 0.0
    width:float = 0.0
    cost:int = 0

def read(deck):
    with open("Deckingcsv.csv", "r") as d:
        line = d.readline().rstrip('\n') 
        counter = 0
        while line:
            items = line.split(',') 
            print(items)
            deck[counter].name = items[0] 
            deck[counter].length = items[1]
            deck[counter].width = items[2]
            deck[counter].cost = items[3]
            line = d.readline().rstrip('\n') #separates another line
            counter += 1
    return deck


read(deck)
print(deck)
```

The CSV doc is:

```
Themon,3.2,2.3,450
Larrec,3.4,3,700
Medrec,2.1,2,500
Parallel,5,4,825
Suncatch,3,3,400
Chantran,9,6,975
```

However, this is returning this error: **TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable, line 18**
Can't quite figure out where this error is cause from, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `deck` is your class (a type). What is `deck[counter]` supposed to mean?

Comment: Your code is using `deck` both as a class name and as what appears to be a list inside the function. Please name your class `Deck`: such conventions exist to forestall errors like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`deck`  is a class. If you are trying to create a deck of items try this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass

class Item:
    name:str = ''
    length:float = 0.0
    width:float = 0.0
    cost:int = 0

def read(deck):
    with open("Deckingcsv.csv", "r") as d:
        line = d.readline().rstrip('\n') 
        counter = 0
        while line:
            items = line.split(',') 
            print(items)
            item = Item(items[0],items[1],items[2],items[3]
            deck.append(item)
            line = d.readline().rstrip('\n') #separates another line
            counter += 1
    return deck

deck = []
read(deck)
print(deck)
```